# Why urlencode data to post via curl and why not doing the same with form?

Tags: php, curl, urlencode

As stated on php manual urlencode is for encoding query part of url, so why should urlencode be used to encoded data before sending via curl too as these are $_POST values and not query part?

```
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
             $value = urlencode($value);
             $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }
    //
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
```

If this is recommended to do, so why this is not necessary to encode posted data via form before processing a submitted form (not for curl, but just processing form I mean.) ?

Does this mean curl is sending data differently than a submitted form does?

Comment: Who says it is recommended to do that? I cannot see any sense in that.

Comment: When you submit a form, the browser automatically URL-encodes the inputs.

Comment: Thanks barmar, 1) so it would be better that I'd always do urlencode with curl? 2) and after receiving posted data from curl no need to urldecode?

Comment: 3) And should I be careful that data is not urlencoded twice? For example user submit a form (data automatically urlencoded by browser) then on next page data will be posted via curl so I should be careful that urlencoding does not happen twice? Or still no problem if I keep that urlencoding forach to send posted data by a form via curl at next page?

Comment: @user4271704 You don't need to use `urldecode()` in the receiving script, because PHP does that automatically when filling in `$_POST`.

Comment: You can set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` to an associative array, then `curl` will automatically encode them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

instead of the `foreach` loop. When you give an array, the parameters are posted using `multipart/form-data` encoding.

You shouldn't call `urldecode` in the processing form, because PHP automatically decodes the parameters before putting them into `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

Comment: Thanks, As you said, with curl if data is array, it will be sent using `multipart/form-data`, so why some codes are doing foreach array to urlencode it before sending it? It seems to be useless? right?

Comment: Because they don't understand that PHP will do it automatically for them.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do the same thing.

Comment: No, it's just another way to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, anyway this foreach is recommended to be there or not much necessary?

Comment: You can either construct the www-form-urlencoded string yourself, or you can give it an array and curl will serialize it automatically for you.

Comment: what about using it always anyway?

Comment: what about using it always anyway?
```curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params)); ```
Is it good idea? what are cons/pros of this way?

Comment: Pro: it's more explicit. Con: it's more to type.

Comment: As php does urlencode on behind and there is no need to that loop, I think there is no need to this function neither? Right? Isnt it just like a shortcut of that loop?

Comment: Yes, it's a shortcut. Isn't that what I've been saying all along?